# How to get an attribute from a list

Tags: java, swing

I have a list into a JTable it display a set of questions. Each question has a difficulty level i want to get the number of easy,meduim,difficult question in the JTable.[image: This is my interface]

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Test test= new Test();
             Integer id=GestionTestDelegate.doGetLastInsertId();
             test=GestionTestDelegate.doFindTestById(id);
             Integer facile = null;
             Question question=new Question();
             if(questions2.contains(question.getNiveauDeDifficulte().equals("Facile"))){
                 facile++;
            }    
             test.setNbrQuestionFacile(facile);

        GestionTestDelegate.doUpdateTest(test);

        }
```

I tried this code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried this code but it didn't work.

Well the code you posted means absolutely nothing to us. It is all custom code with custom classes. We have no idea what "Test" or "Question" are and we have no idea what your methods do.

> i want to get the number of easy,meduim,difficult question in the JTable.

Then you need to access the TableModel of the JTable and read each row of data:

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
int easyQuestions = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < model.getRoWCount(); i++)
{
    String level = (String)model.getValueAt(i, 2);

    if ("Easy".equals(level))
        easyQuestion++;

    // repeat for medium and difficult
}

System.out.println( easyQuestions );
```